# Can you create a local wordpress network / multisite install on a mac with subdomains?

Tags: multisite, localhost, local-installation, mac

Is it possible to create a local wordpress network install on a mac (10.6) using mamp with subdomains? I have tried following some instructions I came across while googling, but apache seems to get hosed when I create virtual hosts. I came across another set of instructions that said only subdirectories will work on a local install. Does anyone know which one of these is the case and have you come across a good set of instructions for how to do it?

Thanks,

Comment: I followed these tutorials and it worked for me:
For multisite folders locally - http://perishablepress.com/wordpress-multisite-mamp/
For multisite subdomains locally - http://perishablepress.com/wordpress-multisite-subdomains-mamp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tutorial was just published at DevPress by Patrick Carey:
http://web.archive.org/web/20111222021406/http://devpress.com/blog/how-to-setup-subdomains-for-a-local-wordpress-network
It should help you. It has been written for Windows but you should be able to translate it into "Mac"

Comment: the link is dead.

Comment: And **that** is exactly the reason why link only answers are no answer...